# AVAudioPlayer sound volume is very low

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, volume, playback

When playing a sound with AVAudioPlayer the volume is very low, you have to hold the phone close to the ears to hear anything, adjusting the volume with the volume buttons doesn't have much of an effect on it.

Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made it work, I set kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker to true and it now works okay.

```
 UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);
```

Swift 2.0 syntax:

```
audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: [.DefaultToSpeaker])
```

you have to place it in a do block

Comment: How do you set this property?

Answer (score 0):

Before playing, use `[yourPlayer setVolume:1.0];` to set maximum volume.

Volume setting with the volume buttons on iPhone sometimes is only effective while your sound is actually playing.

Finally, open your sound file with an audio editor, e. g. [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/). If you see the volume is very low throughout your sound (not filling the whole height of your sample area), use an appropriate filter (e. g. "Normalize").

Do other sound sources (when playing MP3 music or watching video) work well?